# Win10 constantly waking from hibernation by it self

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

I already disabled wake timers and checked my power balance settings etc..
And my PC wont go to screensaver, it wont go to sleep and even if I hibernate it will wake itself up after a very short time.

I am really stuck here, tried everything I can think of.

[image: This is an image of my powercfg and event viewer]